# NSUInteger ошибка

Tags: objective-c, xcode, count

[image: NSUInteger error]

Не понимаю почему возникает ошибка, тип возвращаемого сообщения одинаковый, а Xcode ругается.

Подскажите пожалуйста почему?

Comment: там же написано все в ошибке - функция должна вернуть NSUInteger*, а вы возвращаете NSUInteger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятно, Вы привыкли ставить звёздочку у типа возвращаемого значения метода. Так в ObjC передаются объекты:

```
- (NSTimer*) makeTimer;
```

Это потому, что нужно передавать `адрес` объекта, так как в памяти существует один единственный нужный экземпляр класса. Но для возврата примитивных типов ссылки не нужны, в большинстве случаев это более проблемно, нежели полезно. Поэтому в таких случаях нужно передавать само значение:

```
- (NSUInteger) calculateSmth;
```

Comment: AivanF. спасибо за развернутый ответ! проглядел что возвращается не  объект.